# I have about 200 cells with an equation like [=B6] can you use a MACRO (VBA) to make each cell contain $ in front of column & row characters eg [$B$6]

Tags: reference, cell, freeze

My spread sheet has about 200 cell references and I want to lock the reference e.g. [=B6] to become [$B$6] so that when I order the rows in say alphabetical order the cells still reference the correct original cell

I tried to record a Macro where I used the F4 function to insert the $ symbol in front of the column letter  & row number but it did not work